# Python EPS Visualization Error

Tags: python, python3, visualization, eps

I have installed an open source python platform for data analysis called YT and was trying to run a python script with the following imports:

```
import yt
import numpy as np
import yt.visualization.eps_writer as eps
from yt.data_objects.particle_filters import add_particle_filter
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('agg')
```

However, I get an error of not being able to find the module pyx:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "gasinflow.py", line 3, in
> <module>
>     import yt.visualization.eps_writer as eps   File "/home/samvad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yt/visualization/eps_writer.py",
> line 16, in <module>
>     import pyx ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyx'
```

Python version: 3.6
I have come across this being an issue with Cython not being installed but Cython-0.29.7 is installed too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to install pyx:

```
~$ pip3 install pyx
Collecting pyx
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/a0/75d9d39bbd0bcd3aac7bf909b1c356188734a865552607a8c6bba3bf30bd/PyX-0.14.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyx
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyx ... done
  Stored in directory: $HOME/.cache/pip/wheels/d7/df/3b/33998bf28fc6088c399f64629bcd12f2b129d358f92db5a825
Successfully built pyx
Installing collected packages: pyx
Successfully installed pyx-0.14.1
```

I recommend always using `pip` to install modules since it'll fetch any dependencies any module needs.